# Add a soap Header to BizTalk SOAP adapter

Tags: web-services, soap, adapter, biztalk

We have the webservice xml request as below. for this I have developed the Orchestration. But while we are sending the request to client, we need to add the SOAP header.
Could you suggest me, how can I  do this?

WebService XML Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Request xmlns="http://modeler.ass.abc/efgh/">
  <HeaderReq>
    <PartnerID>E0</PartnerID>
    <TimeStampSubmitted>2013-11-21T18:19:11</TimeStampSubmitted>
    <Version>3.0</Version>
  </HeaderReq>
  <ApplicationREQ>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </ApplicationREQ>
</Request>
```

SOAP Header

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://adb.ddad-sdfad.org/wss/2010/01/fasd-201201-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-10">
      <wsu:Created>2013-10-11T17:26:52.890Z</wsu:Created>
      <wsu:Expires>2013-10-11T17:51:52.890Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-10">
      <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://adb.ddad-sdfad.org/wss/2010/01/fasd-201201-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxxxx</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://adb.ddad-sdfad.org/wss/2010/01/fasd-201201-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xxxxxxx</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2013-10-11T17:26:52.889Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the property WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders

Example:

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml("<headers><Origination>Home</Origination><Destination>Work</Destination></headers>");
```

And then

```
RequestMessageInstance(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

I found this example at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246026.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: with this type I have an issue with my reuqest message, my request message like msgClient.MessagePart1. So, msgClient.MessagePart1 is not accepting the property WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders. Do you have any idea, how to do this?

Comment: @OverflowUser I'm assuming this is a multi-part message? 

I have done this successfully with single-part messages, but haven't tried this with multi-part messages myself.
Have you tried updating your port to use single-part messages instead?

Comment: Hi @OverflowUser, Unfortunately the code is owned by my client, but the principle remains the same. Here is another example I found here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228835/send-biztalk-message-context-to-wcf-service 
Basically: set the context on your multi-part message, not on the part itself.